# Derivative of inner product of matrix vector and another vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

How do I compute:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}} (A\mathbf{x})^{\top}\mathbf{y},
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, $\mathbf{x}$ is $n\times 1$, and $\mathbf{y}$ is $m\times 1$.

Comment: Are A or y functions of x?

Comment: @Tyberius Nope.

Comment: Doesn't A have to be n by n? Otherwise, you can multiply it with x, but the resulting vector won't be able to be multiplied by y. Or else y could be m by 1.

Comment: @Tyberius Whoops, y is a m by 1 vector. Sorry. So the answer to my question is just $A^{\top}\mathbf{y}$, right? :)

Comment: I believe so, it depends slightly on how you choose to arrange derivatives, [see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector_identities)

Comment: the Fréchet derivative of a linear map is the linear map itself, therefore $\partial_x (Ax)^\top y$ is the map $z\mapsto (Az)^\top y$

Comment: @Masacroso I'm not familiar with the Fréchet derivative?

Comment: @Miski123 it is just the most common notion of derivative in multivariable calculus

Comment: You can read here about the Fréchet derivative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative

Comment: Also you can read here about matrix derivative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#:~:text=The%20matrix%20derivative%20is%20a%20convenient%20notation%20for,analysis%20to%20take%20derivatives%20with%20respect%20to%20vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}} (A\mathbf{x})^{\top}\mathbf{y}\right)\mathbf{h}\\
&=&\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(A\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{h})^{\top}\mathbf{y}-(A\mathbf{x})^{\top}\mathbf{y}}{t}\\
&=&(A\mathbf{h})^{\top}\mathbf{y}\\
&=&\mathbf{y}^{\top}(A\mathbf{h})\\
&=&(\mathbf{y}^{\top}A)\mathbf{h}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}} (A\mathbf{x})^{\top}\mathbf{y} =\mathbf{y}^{\top}A. $$